# Cytoscape.js how to shape a node as roundrectangle?

Tags: svg, shapes, cytoscape.js

When trying to set the shape of a node in cytoscape.js to roundrectangle I only get a normal rectangle, no rounded corners. I even tried it in the "Live code examples" from the cytoscape.js. The code is the following:

```
$(loadCy = function(){

  options = {
    showOverlay: false,
    minZoom: 0.5,
    maxZoom: 2,

    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node')
        .css({
          'content': 'data(name)',
          'font-family': 'helvetica',
          'font-size': 14,
          'text-outline-width': 3,
          'text-outline-color': '#888',
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'color': '#fff',
          'width': 'mapData(weight, 30, 80, 20, 50)',
          'height': 'mapData(height, 0, 200, 10, 45)',
          'border-color': '#fff',
          'shape':'roundrectangle'
        })
      .selector(':selected')
        .css({
          'background-color': '#000',
          'line-color': '#000',
          'target-arrow-color': '#000',
          'text-outline-color': '#000'
        })
      .selector('edge')
        .css({
          'width': 2,
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
        })
    ,

    elements: {
      nodes: [
        {
          data: { id: 'j', name: 'Jerry', weight: 65, height: 174 }
        },

        {
          data: { id: 'e', name: 'Elaine', weight: 48, height: 160 }
        },

        {
          data: { id: 'k', name: 'Kramer', weight: 75, height: 185 }
        },

        {
          data: { id: 'g', name: 'George', weight: 70, height: 150 }
        }
      ],

      edges: [
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'e' } },
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'k' } },
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'g' } },

        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'j' } },
        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'k' } },

        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'j' } },
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'e' } },
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'g' } },

        { data: { source: 'g', target: 'j' } }
      ],
    },

    ready: function(){
      cy = this;
    }
  };

  $('#cy').cytoscape(options);

});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Although it was documented, apparently there was something missing in the renderer.  It's being investigated. -Max

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved since version 2.0.2 I believe.